# apache user based on virtual host

Tags: apache, apache2

Is it possible to change the apache User based on the virtual host? when I try to put it within a directory or virtualhost block apache barks. Thanks for any help.

Comment: For Apache to accept an incoming connection, before it knows what host is requested, it has to be running under some user. It doesn't spawn a new process for every request, that would kill the server under any real traffic. So how do you imagine it becoming another user depending on the host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user directive is a global setting and wouldn't work for Virtualhosts. Apache Suexec may be what you are looking for, It will run CGI (or PHP) apps as their respective owner.